# While loop not starting despite condition being met. Returning `function X at Y` when typing command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a start screen for my game which uses two while loops once for the menu and one for the actual game. By default I have `alive` set to `0` and the `location` set to `[0,0]`, when you type `start` the game should `clear` the screen set `alive` to `1` and `print` some text and move your `location` to `[0,1]`. It does all this but the other while loop does not start and instead for example when you type `east` you get `function east at "hex number"`.

```
#imports
import random
import sys
import os

#Define Global Variables
global health
health=100
global alive
alive=0
global wall
wall=1

#Define character
location=[0,0]
inventory=[]

#Clear screen
def clear():
    print ("\n" * 100)

#Define Directions
def north():
    nor=location[1]+1
    location[1]=nor
    return location
def east():
    est=location[0]+1
    location[0]=est
    return location
def south():
    sou=location[1]-1
    location[1]=sou
    return location
def west():
    wes=location[0]-1
    location[0]=wes
    return location

#Check player location
def checklocation():
    if location ==[1,1]:
        clear()
        print ("you are at the start", location)
    else:
        print ("you are headed away from the start", location)

#While loops
while alive==1:
    action=input ("What would you like to do? > ")
    if action=="east":
        print("east")
        east()
        checklocation()
    elif action=="west":
        print("west")
        west()
        checklocation()
    elif action=="north":
        north()
        checklocation()
    elif action=="south":
        south()
        checklocation()
    else:
        print("I didn't understand")

while location==[0,0]:
    action=input ("Welcome to the game type start to play: ")
    if action=="start":
        clear()
        print("You awaken on a forest path")
        print("You are facing east and looking down the path at a house")
        print("There are trees to your north and south and a cliff behind you")
        alive+=1
        north()
    else:
        print("I didn't understand")
```

Comment: I think you need to rethink how this code is organised. You increment `live` within the second loop, but that can't magically send the control flow back to the previous loop. I think you need to have functions for printing the location and getting the user's input for what direction to go in, and put those into a single "game loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is, your loops are out of order. The `while alive==1` loop is skipped over, because that condition is initially false. Setting it to true doesn't take you back to that point. However, if you simply move them around, it will execute as you're intending.

```
#imports
import random
import sys
import os

#Define Global Variables
global health
health=100
global alive
alive=0
global wall
wall=1

#Define character
location=[0,0]
inventory=[]

#Clear screen
def clear():
    print ("\n" * 100)

#Define Directions
def north():
    nor=location[1]+1
    location[1]=nor
    return location
def east():
    est=location[0]+1
    location[0]=est
    return location
def south():
    sou=location[1]-1
    location[1]=sou
    return location
def west():
    wes=location[0]-1
    location[0]=wes
    return location

#Check player location
def checklocation():
    if location ==[1,1]:
        clear()
        print ("you are at the start", location)
    else:
        print ("you are headed away from the start", location)

while location==[0,0]:
    action=input ("Welcome to the game type start to play: ")
    if action=="start":
        clear()
        print("You awaken on a forest path")
        print("You are facing east and looking down the path at a house")
        print("There are trees to your north and south and a cliff behind you")
        alive+=1
        north()
    else:
        print("I didn't understand")

while alive==1:
    action=input ("What would you like to do? > ")
    if action=="east":
        print("east")
        east()
        checklocation()
    elif action=="west":
        print("west")
        west()
        checklocation()
    elif action=="north":
        north()
        checklocation()
    elif action=="south":
        south()
        checklocation()
    else:
        print("I didn't understand")
```